# How To Retrieve Record From Mongo-DB One After One

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I need help, I have 30,000 records in Mongo-DB Collection. I want to retrieve the One Document at a time and next Same Process again.
I'm Using Spring Boot

Like Query :-

```
select top 1 * from StockPrice 
where _id > 00017a813392410dac614961c70c80a8
order by _id;
```

and the next time new id set in the where section for comparesion

Comment: Please post some scenarios like, how you are filtering your records in the query or you don't have any filter condition but you want to get the result from database one by one?

Comment: @Mani plz check the Question

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution by using that method logic for the above query. Hope It's help some one

```
private @Autowired StockPriceRepository stockPriceRepo;
private @Autowired MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
private static String _id = "";
private static volatile Boolean isFirstRead = false;

public StockPrice fetchUuIdAndDate(Integer limit) {
    logger.info("Fetch UuId And Date :- (limit : "+ limit + ")");
    Query query = new Query();
    query.fields().include("date");
    query.with(new Sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "_id"));
    query.limit(limit == 1 ? limit: 1);
    StockPrice stockPrice;
    if(!isFirstRead) { // only 1 time
        stockPrice = this.mongoTemplate.findOne(query, StockPrice.class);
        _id = stockPrice.getUuId();
        isFirstRead = true;
    } else {
        query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("_id").gt(_id));
        stockPrice = this.mongoTemplate.findOne(query, StockPrice.class);
        _id = stockPrice.getUuId();
    }
    logger.info("Query :- " + query.toString());
    return stockPrice;
}
```